# adobe animate - using one animation in multiple html pages / editing file paths

Tags: javascript, html, animation, jquery-animate, adobe

### Image Path Problem

I am building a website, and we have added in an adobe animate animation. We are having trouble with the main image not displaying on multiple html pages in different folders. i understand that it is a problem with the path to the image. I wonder if there is an easy way to edit the file path depending on where the html file is in the folder structure that is calling the javascript file? As i have only one idea that would involve copying the image into every folder so that it would work. Any help would be appreciated.

website structure

```
├──index.html - working 
├──image 
│  └──imageBeingUsed.png 
├──js 
│ └──called.js - path to image = "image/imageBeingUsed.png" 
└──team 
  └──teamone.html - not working
  └──teamtwo.html - not working
```

---

Comment: try this `./image/imageBeingUsed.png` you need to access to upper folder first using `./` because there's no folder image inside js folder

Comment: i know this, then the html file in the team folder works correctly and the index file does not. i am trying to save myself creating multiple javascript files pointing to the same folder from different areas.